# nodemailer attachment text file

Tags: node.js, email, attachment, nodemailer

I failed to attach a txt file that I created earlier in the script to a mail to be sent via nodemailer. The mail is successfully sent however, it is empty. How would I fix this?

```
var nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

  service: 'gmail',
  secure: false,
  port: 460,
  auth: {
    user: 'name@gmail.com',
    pass: 'password'
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
let mailOptions = {
  from: "name" <'name@gmail.com',
  to: 'name@gmail.com',
  subject: 'group_1',
  attachement: [ {
    filename: 'group_1.txt',
    path: /Users/derinserbetcioglu/Documents/NodeJS/'group_1.txt' } ]
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error){
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log("the message was successfully sent!")
  console.log(info);
})
```

Comment: check your path parameter is that the correct path ?
and its attachments rather then attachment

Comment: yes, it is the correct path

Comment: take a reference to the answer provided by @Mustafa

Answer (score 1):

Try the path as path:

```
    '/Users/derinserbetcioglu/Documents/NodeJS/group_1.txt'
    instead of path: /Users/derinserbetcioglu/Documents/NodeJS/'group_1.txt'
```

And i think it should be attachments not attachment

Comment: @thenewbie But it is still correct that you *should* do this (pass a string) and *then* of course also point to the correct path ...

Comment: @davidkonrad what do you mean?

Comment: @thenewbie, I believe the path is incorrect, do you have a `/Users/derinserbetcioglu/Documents/NodeJS/` path in the directory the nodemailer script is executed from? I guess not.  Try the relative path from your script directory to where you placed `group_1.txt`.

Comment: @davidkonrad yes I have the correct path that I got with pwd, the package seems to not work, I would appreciate an example that works, or if anyone could direct me to a proper webpage that works, instead of the top results on the google, which I have gone through in detail